# jQuery load() method returning blank after second run

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am  trying to get data from PHP and enter it into a `div` using jQuery.

The request works the first time round, however, after the second go, it clears the div and makes it blank.

Here is my code for the jQuery

```
var post = document.getElementById('daddress_postcode').value;
var bottles = document.getElementById('bottletot').innerText;
$("#shipping").load("ship.php?postcode=" + post + "&bottles=" + bottles);
```

the PHP file currently just has an echo in it returning a string.

Comment: When do you use the second `.load()`? I guess a conflict may occur.

Comment: Is `post` an empty string after second call to `.load()` ? Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: Open up the console and check the "network" tab. Two things to look for: 1. Does `ship.php` return the correct value the second time around? 2. Are the `postcode` and `bottles` variables set correctly?

Comment: ship.php is returning the value as normal, and the values are set correctly

Answer (score 0):

i fixed my own problem.

the problem was with the vars.
Solution:

changed the request to POST

code:

```
document.getElementById('shipping').innerHTML= '';
var post = document.getElementById('daddress_postcode').value;
var bottles = document.getElementById('bottletot').innerText;
$('#shipping').load("ship.php", {postcode:post,bottles:bottles});
```

This worked

It would appear that the URL joining was working, but instead of returning a string from post, for the URL it was returning an INT, and for some reason (someone might be able to elaborate) it was not changing it.

I am keeping my post method, but tried also explicitly converting the int to a string, worked